# I am wasting my time post PhD due to delay in immigration documents processing. What to do? Please advise

Tags: research-process, postdocs, motivation

Graduated early this year. Was to start my postdoc position in March. Official appointment delayed due to delay in immigration documents processing. Have been losing motivation to work for past two months (just 14 hours/week). Am wasting my time with hobbies and Netflix, what should I do? Please advise.

Comment: Visa delays and procrastination are extremely common.  I'm not sure what advice you are expecting to get.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I am feeling extremely guilty of not working, and feeling concerned how this is going to affect my career. I was expecting some advice on the lines of how I can improve my situation. And if someone had similar experiences post-PhD, what their course of action was.

Comment: Most PhDs have had this experience (visa delays and procrastination), but it's not necessary to have extreme feelings.   If you're distressed, consult a mental health professional.  You already know about the need to apply for jobs.

Comment: I would suggest that this seems more like a personal problem than an academic one. I think consulting a mental health professional for evaluation would be a good plan for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get off the couch and go workout.
2. If you are not 100% proficient in English, study it to complete fluency.
3. Get in the lab (or whatever) and do some papers.  Use the Pomerado to motivate yourself.  Impossible to goof when that tomato is running.
4. Remember, you shouldn't need your advisor to push you.  Especially as a post-doc.  You are supposed to be a budding PI. But, since you are struggling, at least show up and talk to her (or Zoom or whatever).

As for your visa problems, this is irrelevant. You have your Ph.D. Getting an immigration document will not or not should not change your competence, work ethic, maturity, etc.

Comment: Did you actually read the question? "_Official appointment delayed due to delay in immigration documents processing._" The OP is not officially a post-doc yet.

Comment: Irrelevant.    He has his Ph.D.  Getting an immigration document or not should not change his competence, work ethic, maturity.

Comment: A bit harsh, perhaps, but good advice. The OP should be the main driver of their career at this point. Make it so. Few have built a career on whining.

Comment: If you add something about seeing a mental heath professional for evaluation I would vote for this.

Comment: I don't think suggesting to.see a mental health professional would be appropriate beased on this tiny information.

Comment: Regarding #3, depending on their exact status, it may (or is likely to) be illegal to perform work functions without their work permit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In response to a flag, I made some minor edits to your post. Profanity [is not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites) on SE sites, and we strive for a friendly tone (though "harsh truths" are occasionally necessary). I also folded in one of your replies in the comments, as I thought that was an important part of your perspective.